# How should I write to a text file in Kdb?

Tags: logging, text, kdb

If I want to write something to the log, how should I do it? I tried

```
h:hopen `:stderr.log; 
h"test"; 
h "test2"
```

How can I make next entries in different line? also, I wrote a function:

```
logWrite:{[para]
h:hopen `:stderr.log; 
h"para"};
```

It doesn't work because the para is inside the quotation mark. Do you know how I can pass the parameter?

Answer (score 5):

Q1:
To write to new lines - negate the file handle

```
 q)h:hopen `:/test.log
 q)neg[h] "first line"
 q)neg[h] "second line"
 q)hclose h
 q)read0 `:/test.log
 "first line"
 "second line"
```

Q2:

```
logWrite:{[para]
   h:hopen`:stderr.log;
   neg[h] para;
   hclose h;
  };

logWrite["test"]
logWrite["test2"]

read0`:stderr.log;
"test"
"test2"
```

Comment: Hi @Terry if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

> how can i make next entries in different line

Just add a new line character `\n`: `h"some string\n"`

> it doesnt work cuz para is inside the quotation mark

You don't need quotes around `para`: `h[para]` or simply `h para` will do what you want. When you enclose `para` in double quotes you are writing a string "para" to a handle, whereas what you need is send a value of a function argument.